# Is there a way to calculate the max. character length that fits inside a textbox?

Tags: typography, sketch-app, interface-design

This question is not related to specific design software but I'm designing an app in Sketch. Our client will provide all the content but they need to know the maximum character length of certain textboxes (e.g. titles in a cell). Is there a way to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have set up size and font for a certain box you can fill it with placeholder text (usually "lorem ipsum" or "quick brown fox") and this will show you the amount of letters it can fit inside. 
By the rule of the thumb give the number +/- 10%.

Comment: Is there a way to find the exact max. length if it would be filled with the largest character only?

Comment: @Zwaluw what is the widest character, different wfonts ahve different widest char!?

Comment: You're right. In that case I will have to provide an estimate.

Comment: @Zwaluw Only if you are using monspaced fonts. In any other cause this will provide problems as, for example, M and I take different amount of space